# MOUNT.NTFS consuming almost 100% CPU when sf2 or sfz file loaded on Bitwig Studio 5.0 from internal SSD

Tags: mount, ssd, cpu, ntfs, daw

MOUNT.NTFS process is consuming almost 100% CPU when sf2 or sfz file is loaded on Bitwig Studio 5.0 from an internal SSD. Not just for files which are big but even for small files like 10 MB, MOUNT.NTFS is taking up almost too much CPU.

I did a purge and reinstalled ntfs-3g, but there is no change / reduction in CPU usage.

Also, I noticed that the more the MOUNT.NTFS process takes CPU, Bitwig Audio Engine also starts consuming more CPU and goes above 100 percent.

Any idea why this could be happening and how to solve this problem?

Thanks